# How can I click on icon and react datepicker will open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add an SVG icon into `react-datepicker` input but seems like I can't add it with css input so I created a new element for icon and trying to create a function when click into icon the `react-datepicker` will open.

Here is my following code:

```
  <DatePicker
    selected={dateInput}
    onChange={(date) => setDateInput(date)}
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    showPopperArrow={false}
  />
  <span>
    <CalendarIcon />
  </span>
```

Here is my project look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try wrapping `<DatePicker>` & icon within the label?

Code will look like:

```
<label>
  <DatePicker
    selected={dateInput}
    onChange={(date) => setDateInput(date)}
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    showPopperArrow={false}/>
  <CalendarIcon />
</label>
```